# How to prevent inserting the same record in M-M relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have three **EF classes M-M relationship**, configured like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure many-to-many relationship between ExpertisePlan and Lecturer
    modelBuilder.Entity<Lecturer>()
          .HasMany(l => l.ExpertisePlanLecturers)
          .WithRequired(ep => ep.Lecturer)
          .HasForeignKey(ep => ep.emp_num)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertisePlan>()
        .HasMany(ep => ep.ExpertisePlanLecturers)
        .WithRequired(ep => ep.ExpertisePlan)
        .HasForeignKey(ep => ep.ExpertisePlanId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    // Other model configurations...

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

```cs
public static bool CheckRequest(int reqSer, int reqYear)
{
    bool isExist = false;
    using (IndustryExpertCTX ctx = new IndustryExpertCTX())
    {
        var expertisePlan = ctx.ExpertisePlans
            .Any(x => x.req_ser == reqSer && x.req_year == reqYear);
        isExist = expertisePlan;
    }

    return isExist;
}
```

```cs
bool checkReq = IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.CheckRequest(payload_object.Main.req_ser, payload_object.Main.req_year);
List<Lecturer> newLecturers = new List<Lecturer>();
List<int> lecturerEmpNums = payload_object.Main.expertise_plans.Select(p => int.Parse(p.lecturer.emp_num)).ToList();

using (IndustryExpertCTX ctx = new IndustryExpertCTX())
{
    var existingLecturers = ctx.Lecturers.Where(l => lecturerEmpNums.Contains(l.emp_num)).ToList();

    newLecturers = lecturerEmpNums.Except(existingLecturers.Select(l => l.emp_num)).Select(lect => {
        var mainExpert = payload_object.Main.expertise_plans.FirstOrDefault(m => m.lecturer.emp_num == lect.ToString());
        return mainExpert != null ? new Lecturer
        {
            emp_num = lect,
            name = mainExpert.lecturer.name,
            birth_date = mainExpert.lecturer.birth_date,
            current_category_id = mainExpert.lecturer.current_category_id,
            current_job = mainExpert.lecturer.current_job,
            Email = mainExpert.lecturer.email,
            employer = mainExpert.lecturer.employer,
            mobile_num = mainExpert.lecturer.mobile_no,
            nationality = mainExpert.lecturer.nationality,
            SSN = mainExpert.lecturer.ssn
        } : null;
    }).ToList();

    ExpertisePlan expertisePlan = null;

    if (!checkReq)
    {
        expertisePlan = new ExpertisePlan()
        {
            action_type = short.Parse(payload_object.Main.action_type.ToString()),
            batch_name = payload_object.Main.batch_name,
            batch_num = payload_object.Main.batch_num,
            camp_code = payload_object.Main.camp_code,
            camp_name = payload_object.Main.camp_name,
            compos_instance_id = task.sca.compositeInstanceId,
            confirm_date = DateTime.Now,
            dept_code = depCode,
            dept_name = depName,
            fac_code = payload_object.Main.fac_code,
            fac_name = payload_object.Main.fac_name,
            requester_num = empNum,
            request_date = payload_object.Main.req_date,
            req_ser = payload_object.Main.req_ser,
            req_year = payload_object.Main.req_year,
            state = State.FacDean
        };
        ctx.ExpertisePlans.Add(expertisePlan);
    }
    else
    {
        expertisePlan = IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.GetCurrentRequest(payload_object.Main.req_ser, payload_object.Main.req_year);
        if (expertisePlan != null)
        {
            desc = "اعادة اعتماد لعميد الكلية";
            IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.UpdateState(payload_object.Main.req_ser, payload_object.Main.req_year, State.FacDean, DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    var expertisePlanLecturers = existingLecturers.Select(lect => {
        var mainExpert = payload_object.Main.expertise_plans.FirstOrDefault(m => m.lecturer.emp_num == lect.emp_num.ToString());
        return mainExpert != null ? new ExpertisePlanLecturer
        {
            ExpertisePlan = expertisePlan,
            emp_num = lect.emp_num,
            category_id = mainExpert.category_id,
            category_name = mainExpert.category_name,
            notes = mainExpert.notes,
            original = mainExpert.original
        } : null;
    }).ToList();

    expertisePlanLecturers.AddRange(newLecturers.Select(newLecturer => {
        var mainExpert = payload_object.Main.expertise_plans.FirstOrDefault(m => m.lecturer.emp_num == newLecturer.emp_num.ToString());
        return mainExpert != null ? new ExpertisePlanLecturer
        {
            ExpertisePlan = expertisePlan,
            emp_num = newLecturer.emp_num,
            category_id = mainExpert.category_id,
            category_name = mainExpert.category_name,
            notes = mainExpert.notes,
            original = mainExpert.original
        } : null;
    }));

    ctx.Lecturers.AddRange(newLecturers.Where(l => l != null));
    ctx.ExpertisePlanLecturers.AddRange(expertisePlanLecturers.Where(ep => ep != null));
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code has two logical bugs:

- it insert another record in `ExpertisePlan` even if `checkReq` is **true** !!, I don't want to insert record if `checkReq` is true.
- I want to remove any records in `ExpertisePlanLecturers` by `ExpertisePlanId` and `emp_num` before adding any new records.

Comment: Can you add what operations are performed in `IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.UpdateState()`?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove any records in `ExpertisePlanLecturers` by `ExpertisePlanId` and `emp_num` before adding any new records.

this should be conserved on the database level as unique constraint

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertisePlanLecturer>()  
   .HasIndex(EXPL=> new { EXPL.ExpertisePlanId, EXPL.emp_num})
   .IsUnique();
```

or

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertisePlanLecturer>()
    .HasAlternateKey(EXPL => new [] {EXPL.ExpertisePlanId, EXPL.emp_num})
    .HasName("UniqueExpertisePlanId_emp_num");
```

> it insert another record in `ExpertisePlan` even if `checkReq` is true !!, I don't want to insert record if `checkReq` is true.

let me shear with you where I guess the insertion could be happen

```cs
ctx.ExpertisePlanLecturers.AddRange(expertisePlanLecturers.Where(ep => ep != null));
```

the `ExpertisePlanLecturer` has a navigation property `ExpertisePlan` and populated data coming from the following line

```
expertisePlan = IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.GetCurrentRequest(payload_object.Main.req_ser, payload_object.Main.req_year);
```

this data obviously coming from another Context object or any other source

because you instantiate your context by yourself, this context object doesn't know any thing about this data witch may come from the same db. but from another Context if this is the case simple attach to  `ctx` will solve the problem

```cs
expertisePlan = IndustryExpertsModule.Utilities.GetCurrentRequest(payload_object.Main.req_ser, payload_object.Main.req_year);
ctx.Attach(expertisePlan); // << this line attach the data to your context
```